# PHP Ajax Only loads in first row

Tags: php, ajax, loops, ajaxform

I'm trying to run script on php with Ajax but only first row get updated.

I seen some stack overflow posts about classes which I done but still doesn't work for me.

I have php table running in foreach which loads data from sqlite

The form which I'm having issues with in the table

```
       foreach ($result as $row) {
                extract($row);
                
                
              echo '<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="company_id-'.$row['company_id']  .'" tabindex="-1" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="company_id-'.$row['company_id']  .'" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Company ID: '.$row['company_id']  .'</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="mb-3">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#notes">Notes</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#other">Other</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="notes">

<div class="d-grid gap-2">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" disabled>Notes</button>
</div>
<form method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>company_id</label>
                    <input type="text" class="company_id" id="company_id[]"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>notes</label>
                    <input type="text" class="notes" id="notes[]"/>
                </div>
                <center><button type="button" class="save" id="save[]" >Insert</button></center>
            </form>
        </div>

</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="other">
<br>
<div class="d-grid gap-2">
...
</div>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>';
             
            //creating new table row per record
            echo "<tr>";
                echo '<td><span class="badge ' . $exmpl_status_icon .'">' . $exmp_status . '</span></td>';
                echo '<td><button type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#company_id-'.$row['company_id']  .'" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i> </button></td>';
                echo "</tr></tbody>";

                }
```

And JavaScript which I'm using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
displayData();
$('.save').on('click', function(){
    var notes = $('.notes').val();
    var company_id = $('.company_id').val();

    if($('.notes').val() == "" || $('.company_id').val() == ""){
        alert("Please complete the required field");
    }else{
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'addcomment.php',
            data: {
                notes: notes,
                company_id: company_id,
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('.notes').val('');
                $('.company_id').val('');
                alert(data);
                displayData();
            }
        })
    }
});

function displayData(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'data.php',
        data: {res: 1},
        success: function(data){
            $('.data').html(data)
        }
    });
}
});
```

I changed from ID to Class but I'm still missing something during table loop only first row is working second seems like data is ignored as empty string is reported.

If someone knows what I'm doing wrong or have solution on this would be great as after hours of researching and trying different codes no luck. not fan of ajax but needed in this case.

Comment: If you have multiple forms, you need to use DOM navigation relative to `$(this)` to find the inputs for that form. If you just use `$(".notes").val()` it will use the first one, not the one in the form you're submitting.

Comment: E.g. `$(this).closest("form").find(".notes").val()`

Comment: I don't see a `foreach` loop in the code but you mentioned it in the question.

Comment: @Barmar I tried change to
$(this).closest("form").find(".notes").val()

but still same behavior.

To be more clear

This is table inside foreach with same text box (form) on each table called notes.
so the form will be the same for each table just different company_id and notes

Comment: @w.PatrickGale I didn't include foreach as that part of code works perfect
Basically the table is inside
foreach ($result as $row) {

and in table there is form posted in main question.

Comment: Added more of the code as I forgot it's also in Modal which I guess could make big difference (facepalm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it.

I created < ty > element around the form.

```
    var $el = $(this).closest('ty'); //Find parent tr element 
    var notes = $el.find(".notes").val();
    var company_id = $el.find(".company_id").val();
```

Eample

```
 <ty>
 <form>
 </form>
</ty>
```

And made search to closest ty element. Now I understand this logic.

Comment: What is that  `<ty>` tag/element

Comment: @DarkBee
It's made up element which finds the closest element to from.

So if you name it
<something>
Ajax will look in this area
</something>

My code is a mess right now not the best way to do it with above example but I clean up my code at the end. for now it's working. Also learned the logic now how ajax works so a bonus for today.